# asp.net mvc model binding only works on some of the model's member

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have a strongly typed view that has a complex model (a model that has children, grand children etc).

And I ran into confusion because I can't bind all of the model's member. In my case I can only successfully bind the model if I use let say only the first child, and it's grand child. If I try to bind the second child, when I POST back from the view, in my controller I get null.

Anyone ever come across this type of issue? How to overcome it?

the model is here
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/50400766/NewWellVo.cs
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/50400766/WellVo.cs

the view is here
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/50400766/NewWellWizard.cshtml

Comment: can you post your code here?

Comment: :D thanks, I created links to the code, please do view them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you please post the partial view used for the "AddWellActivity" action ?
It seems the data binding problem is there.

Comment: whew you're right, my BeginColletionItem name was not equal to the name of the member of the model, thanks!